# Intellij IDEA changes file permissions on save

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using intellij IDEA and am editing files over a samba connection. On every save, the edited file gains execution permissions. How do I prevent this? Note that "safe write" is disabled.

Comment: See also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152607

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It was due to samba having `map archive = yes` by default. Setting it to `no` solved this proplem